# Impossible to import BaseGameActivity

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have no errors but I cannot had any of these

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
```

I cannot find BaseGameActivity. Even I can't find it in
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples
it was removed!.

How can add BaseGameActivity to my project now!

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: they have removed it see : https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/commit/720e11ebf2935876f63eb4566c2007f3f8a45bc7#diff-8c27e4cb63cba6839c0a9b3c138a51c6R49

Comment: i know that . But what to do now ! .. i need to build my project @SahdeepSingh

Comment: i looked in other branch and found they are using some kind of library https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/appState-archive/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils